# Standard Normal Distribution Z value greater than 3.49 in the z-table

Tags: self-study

Our class was given a problem where Z is a standard normal random variable and we have to look for:

P(Z<6.0) and P(Z>6.0)

I don't know what to do since the value is over the max in the z-table provided to us which is 3.49

Comment: `pnorm(6,lower.tail=FALSE)` gives `[1] 9.865876e-10` i.e. approximately a 10⁻⁹ probability to exceed 6.0.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering if there was a way to solve this without using R

Comment: Without any computational method, the easiest answer is $P(Z>6)=0$.

Comment: Or answer $P(Z > 6) \approx 0.$

Comment: You have internet access, so can go to wolphram alpha, type (without the "") "Z is standard normal; P(Z <-6)" and get the answer 1/2 (1 - erf(3 sqrt(2)))≈9.86588×10^-10

Comment: Thank you for the help. That would mean P(Z<6) ≈ 1 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for the OP's edification.

It is known that $$\left(\frac 16 - \frac{1}{6^3}\right)\phi(6) ~<~ P(Z > 6) ~<~ \frac 16 \phi(6)$$
where $\phi(6)$ is the value of the standard normal *density* function evaluated at $6$.  If your tables of the value of the standard normal *density* function extend only up to $z=3$ or $3.49$, use the formula
$$\phi(6) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-6^2/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-18}$$ to evaluate $\phi(6)$ -- use a "scientific" calculator, not a four-function calculator for this.  You should get an upper bound and a lower bound on $P(Z > 6)$ that differ by very little. Use either (or their average) as the estimate of $P(Z >6)$. It is also known that $P(Z>6) = P(Z<-6)$ snd so the same calculation suffices for both answers.  And there you have it: no muss, no fuss, no nonsense about value of function versus probability.

---

> Original answer for everyone else
>
> For $z>0$, there are known upper bounds $\frac 1z \phi(z)$ and lower bounds
> $\left(\frac 1z - \frac{1}{z^3}\right)\phi(z)$ on $Q((z) \stackrel{\Delta}{=} P\{Z > z\}$.  See, for example, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69417/15941) over on math.SE for a derivation.  Here, $\phi(z)$ is the value of the standard normal *density* function at $z$.  So, try evaluating the bounds when $z = 6$ (using a calculator instead of R since you want to avoid the use of R). You will probably get bounds that differ by very little, and you could use either value (or their average if you like) as your answer.  Presumably you are aware that $P\{Z > z\}$ and $P\{Z < -z\}$ have the same value, and so the same answer will work for both calculations.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this gives me the value of the function but not the probability?

Comment: OK, I am editng my answer to cross the i's and dot the t's for you.

Comment: Thank you. I did solve using the formula from the link you attached and I got the value 1.01x10^-9 for the upper bound and value 1.64x10^-10 for the lower bound.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I did it correctly though. Our professor hasn't discussed to us the distribution using integrals yet. I believe that is the reason why we were given this problem

Comment: That's also why I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this without integrals

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I really appreciate it. I did notice that it was close to Xi'an's answer.

However, when I used the formula (ϕ(6)=12π−−√e−62/2=12π−−√e−18) that you provided above the value that came out was 6.08x10^-9.

I believe that there's a missing 6 before √2π?

Comment: So, $1.01\times 10^{-9}$ is pretty close to the actual value $0.985876\times 10^{-9}$ as found by Xi'an, isn't it? The bound is less than $2.5\%$ larger than the actual value.

Comment: The formula that I gave for $\phi(6)$ is absolutely correct **and there is no missing  $6$ before the $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in the denominator.**  The _bounds_ that I gave for $P(Z>6)$ are also correct as stated.  _You_ calculated $\phi(6)$ as having value $6.08\times 10^{-9}$ which sounds right.  **The value of** $P(Z>6)$ **is bounded above not by** $\phi(6)$ **but by** $\frac 16 \phi(6)$ **which is about** $1.01\times 10^{-9}$ **as you found.**